# Issues loading PHP extensions amqp and grpc. PHP installed with homebrew and extensions with pecl

Tags: php

I installed amqp via pecl. Got the folder 2020

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.2.11/pecl/20220829/amqp.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/amqp-2.1.0
Extension amqp enabled in php.ini
➜  ~ brew services restart php@8.2
Stopping `php`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `php` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php)
==> Successfully started `php` (label: homebrew.mxcl.php)
➜  ~ php -v
```

Running `php -v` shows following issues. With wrong path, not 20220829 but 20200930

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amqp.so'
(tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20200930/amqp.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from PHP 8.0 to 8.2 led to misconfiguration in the php.ini file. I changed `extension_dir` to `extension_dir = "/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20220829"`, rebooted php `brew services restart php@8.2` and everything worked like charm.